# VPS環境で「rootログイン禁止、パスワード認証禁止」としている場合、秘密鍵を紛失したらSSH接続不可？

Tags: centos

**環境**
・VPS
・CentOS7

**SSH接続設定**
・rootログイン禁止
・パスワード認証禁止
・公開鍵認証許可

---

**Q1.この環境で秘密鍵を紛失したら**
・サーバーへ接続不可ですか？
・VPSの場合、OSインストールからやり直すしかない？？

---

**Q2.セキュリティについて**
・セキュリティを考慮する場合、「パスワード認証」は禁止した方が良いでしょうか？
・複雑な「パスワード」を設定しておけば、そこまで気にする必要もない？？

---

**Q3.秘密鍵の管理について**
・どうやって管理？
・ハードディスク故障の可能性を考慮すると、コピーを別の場所へ保管？？…

Comment: vpsがコンソール提供してくれてませんか？

Comment: 「VNCコンソール」というのがあったので試したら普通に接続できました。驚きました。VPSが提供してくれるコンソールでは「/etc/ssh/sshd_config」の設定を反映しないのでしょうか？

Comment: VNCコンソールはシリアルポート経由で「物理的」にアクセスするのと同等なので、sshの設定はこの場合無関係でしょう。 https://webkaru.net/vps/sakura-remote-console/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

コメントしたまま放置してしまっていたので改めて。

Q1に関して、質問内容のようなsshdの設定で秘密鍵を紛失してしまった場合には、物理サーバの場合と同様に基本的にはssh経由での接続は出来なくなるでしょう。

ただしVPS環境ではほとんどの場合が(仮想的な)「コンソール」接続の方法を用意してあるはずなので、そちらを利用してsshの再設定を行えば復旧は可能だと思います。

Q2, Q3についてはVPS環境に限った話では無いので、別の質問に分けてもらった方がよいと思います。
(どこまでリスクを許容するか、によるかと)

なお、質問と回答が"一問一答"の形でまとまるのが理想なので、ひとつの投稿に複数の質問を含めるのはあまりよろしくありません。